# Editing texmf.cnf to avoid "TeX capacity exceeded" error

Tags: pdftex, texmf

I'm getting the "TeX capacity exceeded" which seems to be a common issue, and I've been trying to edit my texmf.cnf file to fix it but it's locked on my computer which is a mac running OS X Maverick.

I accessed the file my going into Terminal and typing:

```
open -a TextEdit /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf.cnf
```

I also tried:

```
sudo open -a TextEdit /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf.cnf
```

I'm having the same issue when I open the `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` file. This may be a general computer question, but I think the lock was done by the software.

Comment: It is often a problem wit a recursion in your document. Are you sure that your text is ok?

Comment: I thought it was very odd to get the error since my source document is only 4283 lines long. However, I was able to find about how many lines LaTeX would allow before the error started occurring. To test whether there was a loop I replaced everything after that with "dummy" text, and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, from the introduction of Lion, such operations are not possible any more. `:(`

However, a workaround is available, I found it at [How Do I open a file as root in TextEdit on Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20199/). In particular [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/20408) tells how to temporarily set the `EDITOR` variable:

```
EDITOR='open -Wne' sudo -e $(kpsewhich texmf.cnf)
```

Quit the instance of TextEdit for saving the changes.

The other methods don't seem to work on Mavericks.

Using `$(kpsewhich texmf.cnf)` is better than using the full path, because you're guaranteed to find the top level file.

Of course there's an easier method, which is what I always use:

```
sudo nano $(kpsewhich texmf.cnf)
```

Change `nano` with `emacs` or `vim` if you're more comfortable with the other editors (I guess you aren't); `nano` is quite easy to use on the Terminal. Just do the edit as you'd do with TextEdit and save the changes hitting Control-X and `y` when the request to save the changes appears.

Comment: That did it! I can edit the file just fine now. Thank you so much!!!