# Doxygen/LaTeX: What is TeX capacity, and how do I edit texmf.cfg to bypass "TeX capacity exceeded" errors? How is texmf.cnf relevant?

Tags: texlive, linux, texmf

I am making some documentation using [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/), but getting the `"TeX capacity exceeded"` error when running the `make` command in the terminal to generate the PDF documentation. This is the relevant part of the error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=3182030]
```

According to the doxygen FAQ (http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html):

---

**When running make in the latex dir I get "TeX capacity exceeded". Now what?**

You can edit the texmf.cfg file to increase the default values of the various buffers and then run "texconfig init".

---

Where do I find texmf.cfg, or do I have to create it (because, if I simply run `sudo find \ -name texmf.cfg` in the terminal, I don't find anything)? In this similar question ([Editing texmf.cnf to avoid "TeX capacity exceeded" error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180035/editing-texmf-cnf-to-avoid-tex-capacity-exceeded-error)), the user had to edit texmf.cnf -- note the *.cfg vs. *cnf extension. What's the difference?

I am assuming that `texconfig init` is to be run in the terminal? I have TeX Live as supplied by Debian "wheezy" (stable). What are good values for `pool size`, or is there any danger in changing the value to some obscenely large number?

---

**Additional information:**

Playing around with `texconfig` in the terminal, I found the following information:

```
=========================== active config files ==========================
/etc/texmf/dvipdfm/config/config
/etc/texmf/web2c/mktex.cnf
/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf/dvips/config/config.ps
/usr/share/texlive/texmf/tex/generic/config/pdftexconfig.tex
/usr/share/texlive/texmf/xdvi/XDvi
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
/var/lib/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
```

There is `texmf.cnf`!

```
=========================== kpathsea variables ===========================
TEXMFMAIN=/usr/share/texlive/texmf
TEXMFDIST=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist
TEXMFLOCAL=/usr/local/share/texmf
TEXMFSYSVAR=/var/lib/texmf
TEXMFSYSCONFIG=/etc/texmf
TEXMFVAR=/home/alien/.texmf-var
TEXMFCONFIG=/home/alien/.texmf-config
TEXMFHOME=/home/alien/texmf
VARTEXFONTS=/tmp/texfonts
...
```

The `TEXMFCONFIG` variable looks interesting...

Comment: It's texmf.cnf you want, `kpsewhich texmf.cnf` on the commandline should show you the active file for your setup. My default texlive 2014 has `pool_size = 6250000`

Comment: Are you sure you need to enlarge pool size? (rather than having an errant document that is stuck in some infinite loop and will eat all the available space however big it is)

Comment: Please put here MWE (minimal working example), which is the source of the error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Fairly certain, since these LaTeX documents are all generated by Doxygen, and are not human-written?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I can't do that, since these are all docs that are generated by code (Doxygen, in this case), and not by hand.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke you've got to have a big document using a _lot_ of new command names to eat 3182030 of pool space, not sure it would fit in the site limits:-) Although I do wonder what this generated document is doing to use that many

Comment: @user89 such faith in machine generated code:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've assumed that there is an erroneous definition, but in a case that you are suggesting the document must be huge.

Comment: Can you show the output of `kpsewhich -var-value=pool_size` from a terminal? Also of `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`. Instructions that mention `texconfig init` are obsolete.